# Activate ssh server on boot

Tags: boot, ssh, systemd

I'm running a Raspberry Pi with Ubuntu MATE 16.04 (I'm a linux newbie) I installed webmin, so I can see that my ssh server starts on boot, but is inactive I read the posting here:

[Start ssh server on boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3913/start-ssh-server-on-boot)

and did all the things suggested...

```
sudo /etc/init.d/ssh start
sudo update-rc.d ssh defaults
systemctl enable ssh.socket
```

Nothing happens. The service loads on boot, but it's inactive.

[image: list of services related to ssh with status]

Comment: Have you installed the SSH server?

Comment: yes... Openssh7.2

Comment: Have you tried sshing to the device? Systemd does [socket activation](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/socket-activation.html), so that the service is started when the socket comes into use.

Comment: ups, that's it...

Comment: sorry, as i tried the first time, i was in wrong wlan

Answer (score 5):

Systemd does [socket activation](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/socket-activation.html), so that the service is started when the socket comes into use. Due to this, you may not actually see an sshd process running after you reboot. Actually sshing to the system should start the daemon.