# How to open a remote session?

Tags: remote-desktop

Earlier, I was trying to find a way to connect to Ubuntu from Windows 7: [Is it possible to use remote desktop from Windows 7 to Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3934/is-it-possible-to-use-remote-desktop-from-windows-7-to-ubuntu-10-04)

The solution was simple enough, I installed TightVNC Viewer on Win7 and I can see/control the current Ubuntu session. The problem is, if there's no active session, I cannot connect to Ubuntu using TightVNC.

My goal is to be able to use Ubuntu that is installed on a computer in the basement from my Windows computer that is on another floor. Both computers are on the same LAN. Ubuntu PC will **not** have a monitor, keyboard or mouse plugged on it. (Currently, while I'm configuring things, it does have those but I want to get rid of it as soon as possible.)

Is there anyway to get Ubuntu to start a session from my Windows 7 PC without having to log in directly on the PC first? Like I can do with two Windows PC using Remote Desktop, I can open a session on a remote computer and the desktop take the same screen resolution as the "host" computer.

By the way, I'm a total noob with Linux and Ubuntu. I got my "For Dummies" book, but it seems that I'm already trying to do things that are not discussed in the book! Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think what you need is is xRDP, as suggested in that other question of yours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install a NX server, such as [FreeNX or NeatX](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FreeNX). Then you can remotely start a session, resize it, and disconnect and reconnect at will.

If you have to connect to a wireless network using NM, you can allow it to connect at the login screen. Right-click on NetworkManager, and go to "Edit connections". Select the connection in question, click "Edit", and check the "Available to all users" box.

Comment: FreeNX solution works very well for accessing linux machines from windows. The contrary requires a paying version (the windows server is not free), but accessing Linux from Windows requires only free components.

Comment: I'm using this set-up in production at work. Around 15 windows machines in different places run some program (not a complete shell) seamless on a Ubuntu server over simple ADSL lines. Using FreeNX in the server and NxClient (the closed client) on the windows machines. Works nicely, fast (even with slow lines) and requires very low maintenance. I'm a fan ;).

Comment: Looks like an interesting options... I'm trying it and I'll let you know if it works!

Comment: It's working! Only minor problem I couldn't figure out how to fix is to have sound streaming to the client. I checked the appropriate options in the Windows client config, but it's still not working... Any idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

- If you only use it as a server use ssh (takes a while to learn but you will love it, cause I do)
- You can set Ubuntu to automatically login (System -> Preferences -> Login Screen I think) so there is always an open X Session
- I think there was once a way to configure exactly what you want in a preferences dialog at the login screen, but I don't know if it's still there, I couldn't find it.

  A Problem might be that Network Manager only gets started after you login, but there might be a solution in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1277/how-do-i-configure-wifi-to-log-in-to-wpa-at-boot-time-regardless-of-user-being-l) thread

Answer (score 0):

http://xlivecd.indiana.edu/

"XLiveCD allows users of Microsoft Windows to connect to remote Unix computers, run graphical applications and have the graphics displayed on their desktops. The software runs from the CD without being installed."