# Auto reconnect wifi?

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager

I use 10.04 on my laptop . Whenever my router switches on and off I have to manually click on a popup ok button to re-enable connection to router . How can this be done automatically ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For Ubuntu 11.04 it automatically reconnects to your wifi.

For 10.04 check [Automatically reconnect wireless connection](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4037/automatically-reconnect-wireless-connection)

or you may need to write a small script with

```
iwconfig wlan0 iwconfig wlan0 | grep -o "Access Point: Not-Associated"
```

`ifconfig wlan0 down` or `ifconfig wlan0 up`