# Problem to start ssh automatic

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, ssh, openvpn

My Ubuntu 12.10 don't start ssh automatic when I boot it.

So when I use [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1277/how-do-i-configure-wifi-to-log-in-to-wpa-at-boot-time-regardless-of-user-being/1299#1299) after I restart my system appear Booting system without full network configuration and I can't use ssh for external clients.

I want to use a openvpn. But how can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I took a read in the link you provided. They seem to forgot a space after `-i` in

`pre-up wpa_supplicant -Bw -Dwext -ieth0 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf`

so it should be

`pre-up wpa_supplicant -Bw -Dwext -i eth0 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf`.

Also, run `ifconfig -a` to confirm that `eth0` is the wireless device, otherwise replace `eth0` with the correct device.

If that still fails, check on your router to confirm that the server is connected and check if `ssh` is running by using `sudo service ssh start`

Comment: Ok, I replace eth0 for wlan0? Correct?

Comment: If that's the device, yes. Not sure why that person had eth0 as their wireless.

Comment: Nothing change When I use "sudo service ssh restart" appear "ssh: unrecognized service"