# Enabling SSH on reboot

Tags: networking, server, ssh, openssh

I would like to be able to use remote SSH to reboot my desktop, from a different network.  After a reboot, through SSH, it will go into the login screen, which would need a password, but the computer won't automatically connect to the internet.  I am not sure how to go about this, but any help will be appreciated.  Also, if it helps, I am using OpenSSH to do this.  Thanks, and have a good one.

Comment: Your question is hard to follow, you have too many variables.  Why doesn't it automatically connect to the internet?  What do you have to do to make it connect?  Why isn't SSH automatically starting?  Or is it, and you just don't have internet?

Comment: @bc2946088 I have SSH enabled on boot, it's just that the computer won't automatically connect to wi-fi. I have a feeling that it has something to do with login keyrings, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Alex Spady if you are using wifi to connect to your router(which is connected to Internet) then you have to set up automated connection on startup... Perhaps you need either the _network/interface_ solution or _Network-Manager_ solution.... But in order anybody to answer your question you have to give more details about your network configuration.

Comment: And also have a look here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/1277/how-do-i-configure-wifi-to-log-in-to-wpa-at-boot-time-regardless-of-user-being